# Regarding Eventkit framework on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

i created an iphone app, in which i m using eventkit.

Framework added just fine, and works fine too.
But now, i am trying to create an iPad app, (same as of iphone), using eventkit,first of all, i dont hv this eventkit framework in existing framework listing.
Secondly, when i tried to add from outside, the app gave me 6552 errors.

Is there any restriction , in using eventkit in 3.2 sdk???

how can overcome this issue

guidance needed.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event kit requires at least iOS 4.0 to work, so this means that it requires at least 4.2 on the iPad.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing you may do is dropping support for iOS 3.2 and require that your users upgrade their devices to iOS 4.3.1. Note that upgrading to 4.2 (minimum required version on the iPad) is not enough, due to the many bugs affecting Event Kit on that version. I am doing exactly the same on my applications, setting as deployment target SDK 4.3.